# How to merge 2 CSV files based on filename

Tags: bash

I have 2 CSV files:

```
1234ABC.stats.csv
name,value1,value1

1234ABC.csv
value2,value2,value2
```

Both of these files have only 1 line in them.

They both have no header, and are in the same directory with no other file types.

How can I add the content from the second file onto the end of the line from the first?

desired output:

```
name,value1,value1,value2,value2,value2
```

Comment: You are searching for `paste` (`$ paste -d, file1 file2`)

Comment: Thanks, if I have multiple files with similar filenames, how can I use paste in a loop?

Comment: See `man paste`: all you need to do is `paste -d, file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 ... file10000`. The manual pages of the linux tools contain a plethora of information. They are really handy to have a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
paste -d, 1234ABC.stats.csv 1234ABC.csv
```

**loop over multiple files in local directory**

```
#!/bin/bash
for statsfile in *.stats.csv; do
   paste -d, "$statsfile" "${statsfile//.stats/}" > "new_${statsfile//.stats/}"
done
```

Comment: If I had multiple files with similar filenames, how can I loop through them with paste?

Comment: i have expand my solution.

Answer (score 1):

(**Edit** fixed a bug — `; $_` was missing)  Off-hand I'd do

```
perl -e  'print join q(,), map { chomp; $_ } <>; print qq(\n)'  *.csv
```

`<>` is a list of all the lines in all the input files.  `chomp` removes the newlines, then `join` adds the commas.

You may need to specify the files manually rather than just using `*.csv` if the order of the results is different than you want.

Or you could do it by hand in a text editor :D .

Answer (score 1):

Try awk script:

```
awk '{printf("%s",$0)}NR==FNR{printf(",")}' 1234ABC.stats.csv 1234ABC.csv
```